# Issues connecting to wifi network in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, wireless

I did a fresh install of 17.04 and having issues trying to connect to my network. I can see all the networks (including mine) but when I try to connect, it just won't let me. Things I have done to try to fix it:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

then add to the bottom and save:

```
[device] wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

After that I do this command 'sudo service network-manager restart'

I try to connect but it never actually makes the connection. I'm using a Alfa Network USB wireless card (rtl8187 chipset) which has worked fine in Kali linux.

This is the error if I try to delete the WiFi connection to start over:

[image]

Never had issues with this wireless card before. Is this just a bug in 17.04 or did I just screw something up?

Comment: The correct patch is... on two separate lines... `[device]` and 
`wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=0`

Comment: @heynnema that's an answer!  :P :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct patch for `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` is to have `[device] wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no` on two separate lines, and change the "no" to a "0":

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=0
```

and then restart your computer.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. The connection is really slow for some unknown reason. Maybe it's the driver for this USB wifi Adapter, I'm not sure. I wouldn't even know where to begin to swap it to see.  Maybe I will install 16.04.2 LTS and see how it goes. Not seeing anything in the software updater that might help. Anyways, thanks again